# function has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, fits

I am trying to write this code and it works perfectly in pycharm. But, whenever I tried to run it after converting into exe it gives me an error "function has no attribute 'read_exif'". The package I am using for this function is not manually installed but, it works without any error in pycharm.

```
def Raw_Fits(self, raw_path, save_location):
    paths = [raw_path]
    bad_pixels = rawpy.enhance.find_bad_pixels(paths)

    for path in paths:
         with rawpy.imread(path) as raw:
             rawpy.enhance.repair_bad_pixels(raw, bad_pixels, method='median')
             rgb = raw.postprocess(no_auto_bright=True, use_auto_wb=False, gamma=None)
    a = np.array(rgb)
    print(a.shape)

    filename = raw_path
    raw_image = Raw(filename)
    buffered_image = np.array(raw_image.to_buffer())

    image = Image.frombytes('RGB', (raw_image.metadata.width, raw_image.metadata.height), a).convert('LA')
    xsize, ysize = image.size
    data1 = np.array(image.getdata())
    print(data1.shape)

    r = [(d[0]) for d in data1]
    g = [(d[1]) for d in data1]
    r_1 = np.array(r)
    g_1 = np.array(g)

    r_data = np.array(r_1.data)
    g_data = np.array(g_1.data)
    print(r_data.shape)

    r_data = r_data.reshape(ysize, xsize)
    g_data = g_data.reshape(ysize, xsize)

    a = cr2fits(raw_path, 0)
    a.read_cr2()
    a.read_exif()

    concat = r_data + g_data
    hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(data=concat)
    hdu.header.set('OBSTIME', )
    hdu.header.set('OBSTIME', a.date)
    hdu.header.set('EXPTIME', a.shutter)
    hdu.header.set('APERTUR', a.aperture)
    hdu.header.set('ISO', a.iso)
    hdu.header.set('FOCAL', a.focal)
    hdu.header.set('ORIGIN', a.original_file)
    hdu.header.set('FILTER', a.colors[a.colorInput])
    hdu.header.set('CAMERA', a.camera)
    hdu.writeto(save_location, overwrite=True)
    print("Conversion Complete!")
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem that occurs during exe execution.
[Error Sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk530.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like PyCharm has access to the package but your exe doesn't. There's nowhere near enough information in this question to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question and included the entire function and screenshot as well. I hope it can help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [this github module](https://github.com/eaydin/cr2fits) then you're reading EXIF data incorrectly.

It should be done like this:

```py
from cr2fits import cr2fits
a = cr2fits(raw_path, 0)
a.read_cr2()
a.read_exif()
```

or

```py
import cr2fits as crf
a = crf.cr2fits(raw_path, 0)
a.read_cr2()
a.read_exif()
```

What my code is doing is making `a` an instance of the class `crf.cr2fits` which has the methods `cr2fits.read_cr2()` and `cr2fits.read_exif()`. `a` then has the ability to use those methods. If you want to learn how to use classes then you can find out more by googling "Object Oriented Programming in Python".

Whether this will fix your `.exe` problem is another matter; packing from python to `.exe` is difficult at the best of times.

Comment: I have used this approach and the problem with exe still exist.

Comment: Then the problem is how you're packaging to `.exe`, which you have told us nothing about. The code on github is not long though, you could just copy it to your code rather than importing it?